# Is this the correct way of joining tables?

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo, html-table

Here is my query.

```
$getdata = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts,
    INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id 
    INNER JOIN address ON posts.user_id = address.user_id
    INNER JOIN favorites ON posts.user_id = favorites.user_id

    WHERE user_id = {$userid} ORDER BY post_id");
```

Is that the correct way to joining multiple tables? It doesn't seem to work for me.

**UPDATE**

Here is the update in a query.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT users.*, avatars.*, posts.*, favorites.* FROM posts
    INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
    INNER JOIN avatars ON posts.user_id = avatars.user_id
    INNER JOIN favorites ON posts.user_id = favorites.user_id
    ORDER BY posts.post_id");

$sth->execute();

$rows = $sth->fetchAll();

if(count($rows) > 0) {

    foreach($rows as $row) {

        ?><h1><?php echo $row['post_id']; ?></h1><?php
        ?><h1><?php echo $row['id']; ?></h1><?php
        ?><h1><?php echo $row['avatar_thumb']; ?></h1><?php
        ?><h1><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1><?php
        ?><h1><?php echo $row['username']; ?></h1><?php

    }
}
?>
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Everything works. This issue has been solved.  Thank you all for your help!  For anyone else with joining tables issues in the future, I would like to mention to check your tables and make sure they are not empty; that's why it was showing blank for me.

Comment: user_id is ambiguous in where clause.

Comment: the comma after the table posts `posts,` is not needed

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues:

```
$getdata = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id 
    INNER JOIN address ON posts.user_id = address.user_id
    INNER JOIN favorites ON posts.user_id = favorites.user_id
    WHERE users.id = {$userid} ORDER BY posts.id");
```

Issues were:

1. Extra comma after `posts` in `FROM` clause.
2. `user_id` would be ambiguous in `where` clause, you want to use one of the joined tables to reference a column.
3. `post_id` would be asmbiguous in `order by` clause, you want to use one of the joined tables to reference a column.

Comment: User 'sunny' below showed to keep the comma and you are saying to remove it.  Check out my updated post with full query. It's giving me major pdo error.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to mention from which table you are selecting what, as you are selecting data from more than one table.

```
$getdata = $conn->prepare("SELECT posts.*, users.* FROM posts
    INNER JOIN users ON (posts.user_id = users.id )
    INNER JOIN address ON (posts.user_id = address.user_id )
    INNER JOIN favorites ON (posts.user_id = favorites.user_id )

    WHERE user_id = users.$userid ORDER BY posts.post_id ");
```

Comment: Please see the updated post. I did your method in a full query. Major pdo error shows. I can not join more than once for some reason.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. dont dont have to use the comma!

Comment: Yep I removed the comma and now the page shows blank.

Comment: remove the comma before inner join and better put each inner joins in seperate curly braces

Comment: only remove last comma after "FROM posts" .

Comment: I did remove that comma. Now i don't get any errors. But I don't see anything on the page either. It's blank.  A question. Does it matter if the tables are not all the same types? my posts table is Myisam while rest are Innodb.

Comment: because your join is wrong. please check again. you join other tables with your base table in inner join. You are selecting "from posts" and joining "on records".

Comment: My mistake. I am renaming my queries to show this example. I forgot to change the names. Everything else is still the same.

Comment: Alright so 2 inner columns work now. 3rd one isn't showing up. Will check the db for name matching.

Comment: Sure I can do that. Only problem is, how do you upvote?

Comment: You should see upvote and downvote options and option to accept answer  on every answer to your question, on left hand side of every answer.

Comment: Oh i see that option is rewarded if a user has a rep of at least 15.  Unfortunately I do not have that privilege at this point. None the less you have been great help. stackoverflow has been excellent in helping me out so far. There is no place else where I can get answers this quickly.

Comment: now, i guess you will have that option soon, i upvoted your question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems `user_id` will cause ambiguity because all your tables are having `user_id` as common field.So while using your query need to mention from which table you want to check the data as like

```
WHERE posts.user_id = {$userid} ORDER BY post_id
```